# how do I turn off whatever causes links to be embedded as URL's site title

Tags: links, embed

When I print a url onto my site, it automatically gets wrapped in:

```
<blockquote class="wp-embedded-content" data-secret="tDj3qpdVAi"><a href="https://www.example.com/">Example Domain</a></blockquote>
```

even though all I printed to the page is "https://www.example.com/".  What is this mechanism and how can I disable either on a specific page or site-wide?

**What I Tried**

- adding the code here to my functions file: https://crunchify.com/how-to-disable-auto-embed-script-for-wordpress-4-4-wp-embed-min-js/
- adding both snippets of code (separately) from here to my functions file:
  [https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-embeds-wordpress/#:~:text=Disable%20Embeds%20in%20WordPress%20With,the%20core%20contributors%20to%20WordPress](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-embeds-wordpress/#:%7E:text=Disable%20Embeds%20in%20WordPress%20With,the%20core%20contributors%20to%20WordPress).

Comment: in order to do this you would need to copy paste the URL into the content, it would need to be on its own on a blank line, and not a link. If you make it a link, or put other text on that line, then the problem would not occur

Comment: it is just a url,  there is no link until this mechanism makes one using the plain text url.

Comment: I'm just describing how the behaviour is intended to work, if there's literally anything other than the URL on the line it won't happen, otherwise a URL on a line on its own that is not a hyperlink will be interpreted as an OEmbed and WP will try to replace it with the relevant embed on display. Try it with a youtube video and you'll see it turn into a video player on the frontend. Knowing this it should allow you to avoid the problem while figuring out the answer to this question, and it provides helpful info for anybody trying to answer it

Comment: hmm you are right, but I want the URL to appear to be on the line by itself... is there an invisible character or `<noombed>` or something that I can put on the line to prevent the transformation but still look like its by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print that plain text url as a link:

```
<a href=“https://example.com”>https://example.com</a>
```